# Memo field value truncated to about 1000 characters when inserted from a .net typed dataset

Tags: ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I'm posting this here because I can't find anything about this on the internet. I hope it's not too localized.

I have a asp.net web site that use an Access database. In the web site I have a typed DataSet that retrieve information from a table including one memo field. The information is correctly red from the Database.

When comes the time to write back to the database (INSERT or UPDATE) the value of the memo field seems to be truncated to little bit more than 1000 characters.

I traced the execution of my application and the value in the DataSet is not truncated before I call `MyDataAdapter.Update(MyDataSet)` (neither is it after the call). However the value is truncated in the database.

What's going on here?

Comment: I'm plagued with this issue right now as well. Everyone points to this article: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html but it doesn't solve the issue of programmatically (C#) inserting into a memo field using OLEDB. Some speculate that if the 1st entry width is less than 256, it assumes that length for all and truncates. That doesn't hold me for. My 1st memo record is 780, and it truncates to 382 when the Access DB write occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing and testing specifically, I would look at the column definition as the table is brought DOWN after connection.  Each column has their own data types (numeric, int, text, etc).  On character based columns, there is a property at the column level for the "MaxLength".  I don't know if that may be set to a base-2 multiple of 1024 which is why it looks like "little bit more than 1000 characters".

If that IS the case, I would try the following, change the MaxWidth to something larger...  2048, 4096, 10000, whatever.

Comment: I just checked again, there is no MaxWidth property on meme fields in Access. I checked on the typed DataSet in my project and the MaxLength value is set to -1, which is supposed to mean "no limit".